# How to get to data-id inside li tag using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="result-card job-result-card result-card--with-hover-state job-card__contents--active" data-id="1946843843" data-entity-urn="urn:li:jobPosting:1946843843" data-search-id="e2f62398-982f-463e-9685-9064dfa810eb" data-tracking-id="UDB/ibIoQvCk1l54VneerA==" data-column="1" data-row="1">
```

I have individual containers in job_posting, I am trying to get to **data-id** and get the number...

here is my code

for job in job_postings:

```
        #Scrapping info from main search page
        
        try:
            job_id = job.find_all("li",{"class"})['data-id']
            
        except:
            job_id = 'No data available'
        job_ids.append(job_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<li class="result-card job-result-card result-card--with-hover-state job-card__contents--active" data-id="1946843843" data-entity-urn="urn:li:jobPosting:1946843843" data-search-id="e2f62398-982f-463e-9685-9064dfa810eb" data-tracking-id="UDB/ibIoQvCk1l54VneerA==" data-column="1" data-row="1">'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = [item['data-id'] for item in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'data-id' : True})]
print(result)
Output:-
['1946843843']
```

Might be useful [beautifulsoap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Lets support el is the element
print(el.attrs['data-id']) # will give you desired answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
htm = '<li class="result-card job-result-card result-card--with-hover-state job-card__contents--active" data-id="1946843843" data-entity-urn="urn:li:jobPosting:1946843843" data-search-id="e2f62398-982f-463e-9685-9064dfa810eb" data-tracking-id="UDB/ibIoQvCk1l54VneerA==" data-column="1" data-row="1">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(htm, 'html.parser')

liele = soup.find("li", {"class":"result-card job-result-card"})    
liDataId = liele['data-id']
```